# 404 not found error with Laravel8 When I use api.php

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I am making simple Gantt chart using Laravel 8 and I have problem.
When I made routing, I got a 404 error when I open the page.
By the way, I'm using xampp.
Besides, I am a Laravel beginner, so I referred to a tutorial on a certain page.
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__howtostart_php_laravel.html

[Error log]

```
GET http://localhost/api/data?dhxr1624612640474=1 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ ajax.js:221
e._execute @ bluebird.js:1164
D._resolveFromExecutor @ bluebird.js:3707
D @ bluebird.js:3258
_call @ ajax.js:176
query @ ajax.js:133
get @ ajax.js:137
t.load @ load.js:21
(anonymous) @ gantt:25
```

[View] `gantt.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 
    <script src="https://cdn.dhtmlx.com/gantt/edge/dhtmlxgantt.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.dhtmlx.com/gantt/edge/dhtmlxgantt.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body{
            height:100%;
            padding:0px;
            margin:0px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="gantt_here" style='width:100%; height:100%;'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    gantt.config.date_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s";
 
    gantt.init("gantt_here");
  
    gantt.load("/api/data");
</script>
</body>
```

[Controller] `GanttController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Task;
use App\Models\Link;

class GanttController extends Controller
{
    public function get(){
        $tasks = new Task();
        $links = new Link();
 
        return response()->json([
            "data" => $tasks->all(),
            "links" => $links->all()
        ]);
    }
}
```

[Route] `api.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::get('/data', 'GanttController@get');
```

I could not solve by myself but I guess this is because routing. could anyone help me please?

Comment: Add a header to the curl request `-H "accept: application/json"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your xampp's apache and mysql services are running , and it's recommended to define you're routes in a new way rather than an old way,
So first start your xampp services and change:

```
Route::get('/data', 'GanttController@get');
```

Into

```
Route::get('/data', [GanttController::class, 'get']);
```

It's new feature in [laravel 8.x](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#the-default-route-files) , then look at your code, you are creating new instances of `Task` and also from `Link`, and trying to get data from them, it's wrong approach.

You should get data like this:

```
$tasks = Task::all();
$links = Link::all();
```

Comment: I solved that after modified route as you told me.
I see that the syntax is new in Laravel 8. I'll read the official documentation in more detail.

Thank you very much